# Javascript fetch data from external url if div table is known

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bit of a struggle here.
I need to make a simple task to fetch image and then on the new line text from certain div tables from external url.

I know what div id's are. All i need is to if i change targeted url from the same website and same div table then images and text will change automatically ( as div tables will not change. Just page will change )

I know it's possible but i don't know where to start actually. Thats why asking you guys.

I was thinking to start with something like:
`Elements itemprop = doc.select(cssQuery: "div id > div > section id") For (Element element : itemprop) { System.out.println(element.text()); }`

This would be for example for text i want to pull out. And then image fetch would be something like this..

`Elements img = doc.select( cssQuery: "img"); For (Element element : img) { If (element.toString().contains(".jpg")) { Picture1 = element.absUrl (attributeKey: "src").substring(0, element.absUrl( attributeKey: "src"); Break; } } System.out.println(Picture1);`

Am i in the right direction? And how i can add to this code the targeted code so it knows from which url to fetch this div table data?
Hope you will help me.
Thanks

Comment: Please may you clarify if this question is about Java or JavaScript?

Comment: Hi it's about javascript sorry

Comment: The reason I ask is because `Elements img` doesn’t look like valid JavaScript